# How should I calculate or estimate this Euler integral of the second kind?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Assume that $\alpha>0,n\in\mathbb{N},$
$$I=\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x^{\frac1\alpha}}dx$$

After I go through the variable substitution $y=x^{\frac1\alpha}$, I get
$$I=\alpha\int_0^\infty y^{\alpha(n+1)-1} e^{-y}dy=\alpha\Gamma(\alpha(n+1)).$$
I'm out of ideas after this step.
I want to find an upper bound about the integral,and any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the question? You have a closed form solution in terms of the Gamma function. If you want an approximation to that function, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Approximations and look at Stirling's formula.

Comment: Not exactly clear what you need. Do you want a way to numerically estimate the $\Gamma$ function? What do you know about $n$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: @Andrei Yes, I just want to find an upper bound on this integral,and I have added the conditions.

Comment: An upper limit of the $\Gamma(x)$ is the factorial of the integer greater or equal to $x$.

Comment: $I \leq \alpha \Gamma(\alpha(n+1))$

Comment: $$\alpha(n+1)=t+1 \implies I_n= \frac 1 {n+1}\, (t+1) \,\Gamma(t+1)$$ and use Ramnujan formula and bounds.